# how to avoid writing the tornado log information to my log file?

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I built an application based on Tornado.

> Tornado version: 6.0.4
>
> Python version: 3.8.5

My code for my log is:

```
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
gen_logger = logging.getLogger("tornado.general")
gen_logger.propagate = False

log_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__name__))
log_path = os.path.join(log_path, "log")
if not os.path.exists(log_path):
    os.mkdir(log_path)
log_file_gen_info = os.path.join(log_path, "log_general_info.log")
# set Formatter for root
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d|%(levelname)s|%(filename)s|%(funcName)s()|Line:%(lineno)d|%(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
)
handler_file_gen_info = ConcurrentRotatingFileHandler(
    log_file_gen_info,
    mode="a",
    maxBytes=30 * 1024 * 1024,
    backupCount=30,
    encoding="utf-8",
)
handler_file_gen_info.setFormatter(formatter)
handler_file_gen_info.setLevel(logging.INFO)
gen_logger.addHandler(handler_file_gen_info)
```

When I need to write some log information to the log file, I use the code like the following:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("tornado.general")
logger.info("my log information.")
```

This log information can be saved to my log file correctly. But I also can find some log information which are not wrote by myself.

```
2021-05-04 18:36:55.407|INFO|backTransmission.py|on_send_success()|Line:168|Sent kafka message successfully.
2021-05-04 18:37:18.461|INFO|http1connection.py|_read_message()|Line:289|Malformed HTTP message from 10.129.98.81: Malformed HTTP version in HTTP Request-Line: 'HTTP/2.0'
2021-05-04 18:37:55.756|INFO|http1connection.py|_read_message()|Line:289|Malformed HTTP message from 10.129.106.104: Malformed HTTP version in HTTP Request-Line: 'HTTP/2.0'
2021-05-04 18:38:00.664|INFO|http1connection.py|_read_message()|Line:289|Malformed HTTP message from 10.144.2.199: Malformed HTTP version in HTTP Request-Line: 'HTTP/2.0'
2021-05-04 18:38:00.725|INFO|http1connection.py|_read_message()|Line:289|Malformed HTTP message from 10.144.2.199: Malformed HTTP version in HTTP Request-Line: 'HTTP/2.0'
2021-05-04 18:39:14.598|INFO|http1connection.py|_read_message()|Line:289|Malformed HTTP message from 10.129.98.81: Malformed HTTP version in HTTP Request-Line: 'HTTP/2.0'
```

The first line is from my log code, the following are not from my log code. but I do not hope to write the following lines to my log file, because there are too many these log records. How to avoid them? I tried to fix it by searching solution from Google, but failed. Any suggestions to me are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tornado.general` is the logger that Tornado uses for its own messages. You should create your own logger for your application, `logger = logging.getLogger("myapp")` Then you can configure this logger however you like, sending its messages to your log file and sending tornado's messages to a different file (or nowhere at all, although I recommend saving at least ERROR-level messages from Tornado's loggers somewhere)

Answer (score 1):

One approach in your case could be to only allow messages of a higher level than `INFO` for other loggers (to remove noise) by implementing a custom [`Filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) object.

```
class TornadoFilter(logging.Filter):
    ALL_LEVELS = "tornado.general"

    def filter(self, record):
        if record.name == TornadoFilter.ALL_LEVELS:
            return True
        else:
            if record.levelno > logging.INFO:
                return True
        return False

# logging setup ...
fltr = TornadoFIlter()
handler_file_gen_info.addFilter(fltr)
```

Conversely you could just use the [default](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L744) `Filter` and initialize it with the name you want to *only* allow messages from that `logger` to propagate and be logged.

```
fltr = logging.Filter("tornado.general")
handler_file_gen_info.addFilter(fltr)
```